# Cannot Disable Migrations after Database Initialisation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

For an MVC5 website, I want to use an Entity Framework Database initialiser that creates and seed a database with some initial values. Next to that I want keep a list of migrations that I want to run in a controlled way when the initial database is created (with some initial values). But whatever I try, the migrations are executed before the initial database is created and seeded.  After a lot of trying and reading up on posts I arrived at the following code:

In global.asax.cs:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new App_Start.ProjectHoursDatabaseInitializer());
```

Initialize looks as follows:

```
public class ProjectHoursDatabaseInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ProjectHoursDbContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(ProjectHoursDbContext context)
    {
        if (context.Database.Exists())
        {
            if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: false))
            {
                var migrator = new DbMigrator(new ProjectHours.Migrations.Configuration());
                migrator.Update();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Database.Create();
             // The problem is that migrations are executed at this point
             // The migrations must not run (cannot run), 
             // The only thing that must happen is creating tables 
             // and inserting some initial data.

            SeedDatabase(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Migration configuration looks as follows:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ProjectHours.ProjectHoursDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "ProjectHours.ProjectHoursDbContext";
    }

    protected override void Seed(ProjectHours.ProjectHoursDbContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

The problem is that whatever I try, the migrations are executed while the initial database has not been created yet. I don't understand this. In the configuration it clearly says that Automatic Migrations should be disabled.
It looks like that is not case. Any idea?

Comment: Database.Create() could be causing issues - it short circuits the initialization strategy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692584/ef-5-code-first-create-a-new-database-and-run-all-migrations-programatically and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately if I replace Create() with CreateIfNotExists() I get the same result, the migrations start without the database being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `Database.SetInitializer<ProjectHoursDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists());` in you Global.asax?

Comment: Yep, that is how I started out. But I tried it again just to be sure. What happens is that the migrations are executed and exceptions occur because there are no datatables. What I don't understand is that simply running the line `Database.SetInitializer<ProjectHoursDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists());` causes the migrations to run. :(

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I solved the problem by just using migrations instead of trying to combine an initializer and migrations. I created the initial migration that creates the database from the package manager:
enable-migrations
add-migration InitialCreate

From there on, I followed the steps in this article to get a working solution that I can use to create an initial database or upgrade an existing production database: https://galleryserverpro.com/using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-to-auto-create-and-auto-update-an-application/